# Why do some artists leave the top off of their airbrush reservoir when painting?

Tags: airbrush

The instruction videos from most airbrush manufacturers always show the dual-action gravity-fed airbrush being used with the tops firmly attached to their paint reservoirs, but many artists choose to run their airbrush with the reservoir open.

Is there an artistic or a practical reason for this (for example, being able to see the paint levels), or is it simply because it looks more interesting on the videos?

[Example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RF_4tgCR1Ng&t=209s)

Answer (score 8):

It's likely because it makes it **easier to see the consistency** of the paint and **how much is left**, and makes working with the airbrush a little quicker: not only because **you don't have to fiddle with the lid**, and **you also won't have to clean it**.
In some cases or situations **it can improve the flow** of the paint when the hole in the lid has insufficient airflow (or is simply clogged) and temporary vacuums occur.
I doubt it is because it looks more interesting in videos, although allowing the viewer to see the colour under different lighting conditions could definitely play a role.

Reasons to keep the lid on include preventing spills and maybe keeping your paint clean when working in a dusty environment.
I have also read about users keeping them on so they can tilt their brushes every now and then to improve the flow of the paint.